# Problema al elegir estructura de datos para realizar búsquedas. C#

Tags: c#

Tengo la siguiente estructura de XML.

```
<piso>
<id>piso1</id>
    <muebles> 
        <articulo>sofa</articulo>
        <precio> 555</precio>
    </muebles>
    <muebles> 
        <articulo>sillas</articulo>
        <precio>12</precio>
    </muebles>      

<id>piso2</id>
    <muebles> 
        <articulo>cocina</articulo>
        <precio>888</precio>
    </muebles>
    <muebles> 
        <articulo>salon</articulo>
        <precio>222</precio>
    </muebles>
```

Mi objetivo es hacer lo siguiente:
Dado un piso y un artículo me gustaría obtener su precio. ¿Que estructura de datos usuarias para guardar la información del XML? Debe ser una estructura que permita una búsqueda muy rápida... Yo había pensado en usar un DataDictionary, usar como clave/valor algo así:
piso1_sofa : 555; 
piso1_sillas : 12

Os parece una buena idea?

Gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y pq no serializarlo en objetos y buscar en los objetos despues? al fin y al cabo, va a terminar siendo lo mismo.

Answer (score 6):

El xml que presentas no es valido, para conocer los articulos por piso deberian agruparse de alguna forma.

```
<pisos>
    <piso>
        <id>piso1</id>
        <muebles> 
            <articulo>sofa</articulo>
            <precio> 555</precio>
        </muebles>
        <muebles> 
            <articulo>sillas</articulo>
            <precio>12</precio>
        </muebles> 
    </piso>
    <piso>
        <id>piso2</id>
        <muebles> 
            <articulo>cocina</articulo>
            <precio>888</precio>
        </muebles>
        <muebles> 
            <articulo>salon</articulo>
            <precio>222</precio>
        </muebles>
    </piso>
</pisos>
```

Entonces con la ayuda del sitio

[xmltocsharp](https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/)

Puedes obtener una clase equivalente para deserializar

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Xml2CSharp
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName="muebles")]
    public class Muebles {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="articulo")]
        public string Articulo { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="precio")]
        public string Precio { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="piso")]
    public class Piso {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="muebles")]
        public List<Muebles> Muebles { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="pisos")]
    public class Pisos {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="piso")]
        public List<Piso> Piso { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Si deserializas puedes aplicar `linq` en la busqueda.

Algo como esto:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string xmlString = @"<pisos>
                                <piso>
                                    <id>piso1</id>
                                    <muebles> 
                                        <articulo>sofa</articulo>
                                        <precio> 555</precio>
                                    </muebles>
                                    <muebles> 
                                        <articulo>sillas</articulo>
                                        <precio>12</precio>
                                    </muebles> 
                                </piso>
                                <piso>
                                    <id>piso2</id>
                                    <muebles> 
                                        <articulo>cocina</articulo>
                                        <precio>888</precio>
                                    </muebles>
                                    <muebles> 
                                        <articulo>salon</articulo>
                                        <precio>222</precio>
                                    </muebles>
                                </piso>
                            </pisos>";

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Pisos), new XmlRootAttribute("pisos"));
        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xmlString);
        Pisos pisos = (Pisos)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);

        var result = (from piso in pisos.Piso
                     from mueble in piso.Muebles
                     where piso.Id == "piso2" 
                           && mueble.Articulo == "salon"
                     select mueble).FirstOrDefault();

        if(result == null){
            Console.WriteLine("no existe");
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Precio: {0}", result.Precio);
    }
}


    [XmlRoot(ElementName="muebles")]
    public class Muebles {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="articulo")]
        public string Articulo { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="precio")]
        public string Precio { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="piso")]
    public class Piso {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="muebles")]
        public List<Muebles> Muebles { get; set; }
    }

   [XmlRoot(ElementName="pisos")]
    public class Pisos {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="piso")]
        public List<Piso> Piso { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Tengo que hacer muchísimas búsquedas y me preocupa el tiempo, ya que el XML será grande. Crees que el uso de linq sería optimo? Creo un Dictionary mejor?

Comment: a que llamas grande ? como llegarias del xml al dictionary? eso tampoco parece que vaya ser mas performante

Comment: El XML tendría cientos de miles de pisos. Crees que la búsqueda sería optima con un Linq?

Comment: si lo planteas asi usar un xml ya es una locura, deberias tener un proceso que lo importe a una db y aplicar las busquedas usando sql. Ya no es cuestion de linq si o no, filtrar sobre ese xml ya seria incorrecto nada seria performante ante cientos de miles de datos